# python regex, remove escape characters and punctuation except for apostrophe

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"aaa\n\t\n asd123asd water's tap413 water blooe's"
```

How can I remove all escape characters, numbers, and punctuation except apostrophe using regex?

I'm pretty new to regex, and would appreciate it if you can explain what each expression means, if the regex formula is to be complicated

Comment: Please define what you mean by "escape characters".

Comment: @Jan \n \t \r ....

Comment: @EricKim Did you have a look at the python page for the `re` module in charge of regular expressions? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) It's quite well explained there, I use it as my go-to document when I do regex stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for a search and replace method, which in Python should be `re#sub()`.

Simply replace non-letters & apostrophe (`[^a-zA-Z' ]+`) with `''` (nothing).

- Oh well, what about the escaped characters?
R: They will turn into a single character when inside the string,  `\n` will be turned into a newline character for example, which is not a letter or a `'`.

Instead, if you actually have escaped an escaped character in your string (like: `"abc\\nefg"`), you should add a `\\\\.|` at the start of your regex, which will match the backslash + any other character (so it will be: `\\\\.|[^a-zA-Z' ]`)

Here is the working exemple:

```
import re
s = "aaa\n\t\n asd123asd water's tap413 water blooe's"
replaced = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z' ]+", '', s)
print(replaced)
```

https://repl.it/repls/ReasonableUtterAnglerfish

---

> Would appreciate it if you can explain what each expression means

So, the explanation:

- `\\\\` - Matches a backslash (Why four? Each pair will escape the slash for the Python string's compilation, which will turn into a `\\` which is how you match a backslash in regex).
- `.` - Match any character except for the newline **character**.
- `|` - OR expression, matches what is before OR what is after.
- `[^...]` - Must **NOT** be one of these characters (inside).
- `a-zA-Z'`  - Match characters from `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `'` or  .
- `+` - Quantifier, not needed here, but would be good to reduce the matches, hence reduce the time of execution (Which would translate as "One or more occurrences of the term behind").

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
snt="aaa\n\t\n asd123asd water's tap413 water blooe's"
"".join(re.findall("[^\n\t\d:.,]+",snt))
```

Answer (score -1):

I not sure what are you specifically browse, but `((\\n|\\t|\.|\ |\,|\;)+)+` can select your specification ... try your own regex in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com)